# c# wpf SystemColors doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, systemcolors

I'm trying to color my Window with systemcolors but when I do it like this:

```
<Menu
    Width="Auto"
    Height="20"
    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarColor}}"/>
```

I'm getting a 8-digit hexnumber. My program does only accept 3 or 6 numbers for colors. Executing the program always gives an error message

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Zeilennummer "11" und Zeilenposition "4" 
von "Beim Festlegen der Eigenschaft" System.Windows.Controls.Panel.Background 
"wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.". ---> System.ArgumentException: "#FFF0F0F0" ist 
kein gültiger Wert für die Eigenschaft "Background".
```

if I use "MenuBarColorKey" instead this will not be accepted as vaild value either. But then the text reads ' "MenuBarColorKey" is not a valid value....'

How can I correct this?

Thanks for your help

Michael

edit:
@AwkwardCoder

Sorry, reading already a few years, I am new to writing in stackoverflow, so I can't comment or vote.

You are right. With brush it works. Thank You Very Much!

But I referred for the names to the utility from 
Zack Peterson as shown in

"wpf - How do I use the correct Windows system colors?"

and there I didn't find the extension "Brush". And this utility works for me.

Comment: Have you tried `SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey` instead?

Comment: In WPF, the 8 digit hexadecimal number for colours is the same as the 6 digit number that your program uses, but with 2 extra digits (at the beginning) that relate to the colour's Alpha channel (opacity): `#AARRGGBB`.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 problems here. First you want to use `Color` for a `Brush` property and second you try to use `Color` as a resource key.

If you want to use it as a resource you need to use [`SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.menubarbrushkey(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}}"
```

or you can use it directly and then you should use [`SystemColors.MenuBarBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.menubarbrush(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Background="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrush}"
```

You'll find that [`SystemColors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you 4 static properties for each colour

- `XxxxColor` gives you  `Color` structure
- `XxxxColorKey` gives you `ResourceKey` to `Color` structure
- `XxxxBrush` gives you `SolidColorBrush` class
- `XxxxBrushKey` gives you `ResourceKey` to `SolidColorBrush` class

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx) there is NOT a `MenuBarColor`, there is a `MenuBarBrush`